# Create a lightswitch shell

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I would like to create a new lightswitch shell(because I need another layout than the default one).

So I've:

VS 2010 premium
VS 2010 SP1 SDK
Lightswitch 2011
Lightswitch 2011 Extension toolkit(with the target file correctly installed).

So I'm starting to follow this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290138.aspx)
I create the Lightswitch Extension project(c#), then I tried to add a new item to the .Lspkg project, but I did get this error:

[image: Error when I add the shell item]

But this project exists!!!

[image: Project list]

I don't know if this error has something to do with it, but all references to a silverlight project of the .lspkg have a warning:

[image: Package references warning]

I tried to delete and create the whole project, with another name, several times: no changes
I tried to delete and restore the broken references: no changes
I tried to build the solution before adding the item: no changes
I tried to close and restart VS: no changes
I tried to reboot: no changes

I googled a lot, but I didn't found a solution :(. This is vital for me, I need to create this or I can throw a big project, so please help, I'm really desesperate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to make it works! I was having this project in a "Solution Folder", and it seems it doesn't work if it is in a Solution Folder. Sad, but at least now I can make it works

Comment: thanks to share your solution. Perhaps you want to include a picture of your new shell ;)